# Value of key for Model object gained dynamically

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to gain a value from an associated table linked via a field in a table using the following (where i is created in an `each` loop):

```
value = current_user.question["convq#{i}"].id
```

My table has references from the `Questions` table to a `Questionsbank` table in the form of columns named convq1_id, convq2_id ... convq3_id.

I simply want to cycle through each field in `Questions` and gain the `questionbank.text` field.

Sadly, the above will only give me the physical value in the question table field not a link to the associated record using the following code:

```
(1...9).each do |i|
  value = current_user.question["convq#{i}"].id
end
```

Can anyone let me know how I can cycle through table and gain the associated 'id' or text value of the referenced record?

Thanks in advance.

Each model is set up as:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :convq1, :class_name => 'Questionbank'
  belongs_to :convq2, :class_name => 'Questionbank'
  belongs_to :convq3, :class_name => 'Questionbank'
  belongs_to :convq4, :class_name => 'Questionbank'
  belongs_to :convq5, :class_name => 'Questionbank'
  belongs_to :convq6, :class_name => 'Questionbank'
  belongs_to :convq7, :class_name => 'Questionbank'
  belongs_to :convq8, :class_name => 'Questionbank'
  belongs_to :convq9, :class_name => 'Questionbank'
  has_many :questionbanks

end
```

and ...

```
class Questionbank < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :likes
  has_many :questions

end
```

Comment: try with

conq = current_user.question.send("conq#{i}")
value = conq.id

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question. You want to reach a particular questionbank that contains the value in conq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you might be looking for:

```
(1...9).each do |i|
  value = current_user.question["convq#{i}"]
  questionbank = Questionbank.find_by( question: "{value}")
  questionbank.id
end
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I did try this but questioned if this was the "best" way to do it. Now that you've confirmed that I'm on the right lines I thank you most kindly!